# Using gyroscope in an iPhone to find distance

Tags: ios, swift, math, gyroscope

Is the gyroscope in an iPhone accurate enough to find distance in the same way that a measuring tape could, I am not looking at using GPS as I would plan on this only working for short distances.  If so how would I calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, "no".

A more complete answer is:  the gyroscope measures rotation, not distance.  It is possible to use the gyroscope to *help* measure distance, but it would have to be coupled with some other sensor that can actually measure distance.

I will go farther and mention that, the accelerometer packaged with the gyroscope, by itself, can't measure distance, either.  Even though the accelerometer measures acceleration, which is more closely related to distance than rotation, it needs some kind of absolute reference to give you a useful distance.

For an iPhone, your best bet is to use the camera, and computer vision techniques, combined with the gyroscope and accelerometer, to do integrated tracking of your stationary environment.  The tricky bit will be reliably ignoring non-stationary things in your environment...